# Should a library be imported for the built in Python function sort()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following program written with Python 2.7

```
numbers = [25, 03, 91, 59, 10, 12, 6, 9]
print(numbers)
print (numbers.sort())
```

The output is:

```
[25, 3, 91, 59, 10, 12, 6, 9]
None
```

Why is it returning None?

Comment: Because it's in-place; it sorts the old list, rather than returning a new one, so doesn't explicitly return anything. If it needed importing (it doesn't, it's a list instance method) you'd get a `NameError`.

Comment: Try printing `numbers` again after `numbers.sort`. It's been sorted in place.

Comment: `sorted(numbers)` will return a new, sorted list.

Answer (score 3):

It's returning `None` because `sort()` will change the list in place, it does not return a new list:

```
>>>> numbers = [25, 03, 91, 59, 10, 12, 6, 9]
>>>> print(numbers)
[25, 3, 91, 59, 10, 12, 6, 9]
>>>> numbers.sort()
>>>> print(numbers)
[3, 6, 9, 10, 12, 25, 59, 91]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's `sort()` sorts a list in place and returns `None`. If you want to print the sorted list, just print the list again.

```
numbers = [1,4,2,3,5]
print(numbers)  # prints [1,4,2,3,5]
numbers.sort()
print(numbers)  # prints [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Further, Python has a builtin `sorted()` which returns a copy of the list, sorted.

```
numbers = [1,4,2,3,5]
print(numbers)          # prints [1,4,2,3,5]
print(sorted(numbers))  # prints [1,2,3,4,5]
```